# How to create WAR for a composite project in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, buildship

I am using Eclipse Buildship V2.1.2 for Gradle. I have two independent web projects, P1 and P2 and a project, P3 which acts as dependency for all other projects. My task is to create one main build with which I can build and generate WAR files from P1 and P2 and JAR file from P3. I should include this P3 jar file as dependency for P1 and P2. I have created a `composite-build` with following structure,

Composite-project

- P1

  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
- P2

  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle
- P3

  - build.gradle
  - settings.gradle

build.gradle

settings.gradle

Composite-project -> build.gradle:

```
task run {
    println "Tasks: services"
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('P1').task(':run')
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('P2).task(':run')
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('P3).task(':run')
}
```

Composite-project -> settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'services'
includeBuild 'P1'
includeBuild 'P2'
includeBuild 'P3'
```

P1 -> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
defaultTasks 'run'

task run {
   println "Tasks: cluster"
  buildDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "gradleBuild/" + project.name)
}
```

Now, if I run build of 'Composite-project', all the projects are configured but WAR files and JAR file is not created. The war files gets created only if build is run for that project. How to accomplish this task?

Comment: You need to run `build` task to prepare the artifacts why `run`?

Comment: I am newbie. I assumed that task run is executed and confirmed with the print inside it.  I also assumed that build directory which is given inside task run will get created. Should I specify new task to create WAR location?

Comment: Is this project structure recommended? Placing other projects inside a composite project does not give package exploring structure in eclipse. Or should I place all projects outside the composite project and just refer it?

Comment: With the `print` in `run` you should assume that task was _configured_ not actually _executed_. Read about configuration vs execution. There's a `war` plugin, you can apply it and use. Is your project eclipse-driven?

Comment: I use Luna eclipse 4.4. Every time to run task, I use `Gradle Tasks` and right click on build  (build of composite-project) -> Run gradle tasks. I get output as `:war UP-TO-DATE`. But WAR file is not created. If I do the same in P1 build, I get war file. Am I doing it wrong or everytime i need use that particular project's build?

Comment: I referred `gradle-4.3.1\samples\compositeBuilds\basic` for creating composite build structure.  But having all the projects inside a single composite project does not seems to be good for developing in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case and solved it like this.

Firstly define a `buildAll` task for each project:

```
task buildAll(type: GradleBuild) {
    tasks = [ 'build' ]
}
```

Then define a root `buildAll` task for the composite project:

```
task buildAll {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuilds*.task(':buildAll')
}
```

After that calling `gradle buildAll` will build all nested projects and you will get needed build artifacts.

**See Also**

- [Defining a composite build only to build all subprojects](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/defining-a-composite-build-only-to-build-all-subprojects/25070)
- [Depending on tasks in an included build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#included_build_task_dependencies)

And there is [the example](https://github.com/AlexMAS/gradle-composite-build-example) on GitHub which I prepared specially for this case.